# How to properly store an array of constant data?

Tags: c++

My question is particularly pointed towards what's neat and efficient and won't get me made fun of as a programmer.

So basically I want to store a huge file of names of PNGS. So of course I'd use an array of strings in order to store all those names. But my question is should I store these strings in something like a binary file? Or should I just put them straight onto the script? I personally hate the idea of using a text file to store them but what do I know.

If I were to put them on a script then it would look something like this:

```
const std::string tileFile[textureAmount] ={
    "Grass.png",
    "Dirt.png"
};
```

But this just looks really stupid to me for some reason. How would one handle a situation like this more professionally?

Comment: If it's a large enough list, or you might expect the exact contents of it to change without the rest of the underlying source code changing, making it a text file seems pretty reasonable. What's your objection to that?

Comment: Depending on how many 'PNG' files you are going to be working with you could store the file names in a CONST file. That or you could try and rename the PNG files with a form of mapping that would allow you to do some fast #BASENAME#+IDENTIFIER for search. 

Depending on how the structure/point of the program you could throw all of the names into a STATIC array. If these files will constantly change names/need additions I would rethink the strategy of naming conventions. If it is a set list then you have some options available.

Comment: @Stonen2 I was actually thinking about this too.. But there are quite a few PNG files and the idea is to stay organized and renaming all of them will cause serious confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A character is 1 byte, whether you write a text file or a binary file.  The only savings would be if you did some encoding or compression to it, and text does compress nicely since not all the bits in the chars are usually used.

But one pragmatic rule for programming is, "remember the power of plain text".  Binary is nice, but if you don't need it, don't use it.  Text is easier to work with, to read, to understand when it is corrupted, to use with other tools, and so on.  If you can map the data into memory, use binary.  If you're going to gzip it or something like that, use binary.  If you're just storing the data and it's not excessively big, then I'd recommend a nice, easily parsed text file.

And don't feel ashamed of it.  :)